# Login redirect to specifc page according to user rank

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, authentication

I have the following jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#login').click(function()
   {
         var username=$("#username").val();
         var password=$("#password").val();
         var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
         if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0)
         {
               $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "ajaxLogin.php",
                  data: dataString,
                  cache: false,
                  beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").val('Connecting...');},
                  success: function(data){
                        if(data)
                        {
                              $("body").load("<?php echo $_POST[$page]; ?>").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             $('.login-block').shake();
                             $("#login").val('Login');
                             $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error: Invalid username or password. </span>");
                       }
                 }
           });

         }
         return false;
   });
});
```

and `ajaxLogin.php`:

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    session_start();
    if(isSet($_POST['username']) && isSet($_POST['password']))
    {

        $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
        $password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']));

        $result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT ID FROM Students WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' UNION SELECT ID FROM Teachers WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'   ");
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if($count==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$row['ID'];
            echo $row['ID'];
            switch ($row['rank']) {
                case 'student': 
                $page="student.html";
                break;

                case 'teacher':
                $page="mainPage.html";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I am trying to redirect users to a different page based on their rank, which is a column from my table. So far I didn't manage to use the rank in anyway because I keep getting errors. Secondly, in my jQuery in the success part, I am loading only that specific page, how could load the specific page base on the rank?

Comment: AJAX is all about communication between client and server without reloading the page - so your script - ajaxLogin.php should send something back - for example a json_encoded array, which is available via the data parameter of your success method.

Comment: @axel.michel you mean that i should send from ajaxLogin.php back to success a json encode array with the page name?

Comment: yes, this is what AJAX is about. For a more detailed guide you might look here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php